# Filter lines of file matching pattern and only print a part of it

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have personal files where I declare functions like so:

```
function funcname {
    # ...
}
```

I would like a command that outputs every funcname in the file, like so:

```
funcname1
funcname2
...
```

I don't understand why this command does not work:

```
cat filename | sed -ne '/^function.*{$/p' -e 's/function \([0-9a-zA-Z_]+\) {/(\1)/'
```

while this one does (it gives the one branch that is currently active):

```
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1) /'
```

Right now I could use this instead:

```
cat filename | grep '^function' | cut -d' ' -f 2
```

But I would really like to understand what's wrong with the command above (the 1st one).

Comment: I removed the edit notice; it doesn't really belong in the question. Though it makes sense to keep as a comment like this for a while.

Comment: Ok Thank you triplee

Answer (score 2):

**Edited** to incorporate the case mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261735/filter-lines-of-file-matching-pattern-and-only-print-a-part-of-it/48262136?noredirect=1#comment83512321_48262136) comment.

Bash function definitions can be written with our without `function` keyword like below

```
# cat 48261735 
function testfun1
{
echo "testfun1"
}
testfun2()
{
echo "testfun2"
}
function testfun3{
echo "testfun3"
}
```

**Script to get all function  names**

```
# sed -nE -- '/function/s/^.*function[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]{}]*).*$/\1/p;/\(\)/s/^[[:blank:]]*([^(]*).*$/\1/p' 48261735
testfun1
testfun2
testfun3
```

---

**Now**, what went wrong with your script.

To start with you did [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). The file can be directly fed into the script using `--` to notify the `sed` that we are finished with the parameters. The `--` is a workaround for the corner case that your filenames start with a `-`. Below is an example

```
sed 'your parameters and script here' -- filename
```

Then, your first expression

```
-e '/^function.*{$/p'
```

id out of place. Do you really wish to print stuff before you actually make the substitution? Instead you could add a p flag after the `s` command to tell `sed` that whatever is the result of the substitution should be print to the stdout

Now, coming to the substitution part, you are not accounting the  multiple spaces that can come before and after the function keyword and function name.

***More importantly***, since you're not using the extended regular expression, you're missing the escape character before the `+` in your selection part. So you could come up with something like

```
sed -ne '/^[[:blank:]]*function.*/s/^[[:blank:]]*function[[:blank:]]*\([0-9a-zA-Z_]\+\)[[:blank:]]*{*/\1/p' -- filename
testfun1
testfun3
```

Note the `p` flag after the `s` command which overrides the `-n` option. Evenn then your script would miss the `testfun2` because it is not accounting for the `functon_name()` format.

I suggest you use the extended regex option of `sed` ie -E which will help you avoid a lot of escape sequences.

Hope things are clear. <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Comment: for my case, the opening curly brace is still in the final output, but apart from that it works. I did reformulate the question to make it more obvious that I want to understand what is wrong in the command

Comment: @RomainVincent : I have put a workaround for the slipped cases and given an explanation for why your script didn't work and some suggestions.